# How to specify source IP address in python websocket?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, websocket, ip

I have several IP addresses configured on my network interface card. I need to specify through which local IP address python websockets must connect. Is it possible?

```
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://example",
                                on_open=on_open,
                                on_message=on_message,
                                on_error=on_error,
                                on_close=on_close,
                                )

ws.run_forever()
```

I tried SourceAddressAdapter, but i cant configure it for websockets

Comment: According to the docs https://websocket-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/app.html#websocket._app.WebSocketApp you can pass a "pre-initialized stream socket"

Comment: can you pls share any example?

Comment: A stream socket is a plain TCP socket like in the most network client examples,   just bind your local address before connecting.